# Blackberry - accessing other class instance context

Tags: class, blackberry

I'm coming from Android and now I'm learning for Blackberry.

In Android to access other class we can pass it's context similar "this" in java. How to do it in Blackberry? The problem is in Blackberry I would like to add a field/manager of Screen class in other class, example of the code:

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
//Creates a new MyScreen object

   public MyScreen()
   {        
    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle");
    process1 x = new process1(); // will add the labelfield
   }
}
```

this in other file class

```
public class process1
{
   public process1()
   {        
    //i'm trying to get the context of MyScreen so i can add the field in this class
     MyScreen.add(new Labelfield("test"));
    //but its giving error with the message cannot make static reference
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the process1 constructor to take a MyScreen object:

```
public process1(MyScreen screen)
   {        
     screen.add(new Labelfield("test"));
   }
```

Comment: And use `this` when calling the constructor: `process1 x = new process1(this);`